# Structure Module breaks after 1000 entries

Tags: structure

I cannot reorder pages after reaching 1000 entries in Structure. I get the following error:

"Reordering Failed\n\nYour Structure Tree appears to be out of date.\n\nSomeone else may be editing or you may have another tab with a newer Structure tree.\n\nPlease refresh and try reordering again"

If I delete #1000 and get to 999 it works fine. Why would there be a limit? I can't get EEHarbor to respond to me. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

Try upping this PHP runtime value (either in your actual PHP `ini` file or in your `system/index.php` file via `ini_set`).

Like, really, try upping it to 50000.

Comment: That did it. Thank you